# Watson Studio Job API

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I am trying to run a job created in IBM Watson Studio using a post call from this link that provides the ability to test : https://api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/v2/jobs/docs/swagger/#/Job_Runs/job_runs_create

[image]

but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "reason": "CATSV5025E: Unable to find Catalog for project 'a7b54be1-c319-4bca-bd21-13ff6577edd9'",
  "message": "An error occurred while retrieving the asset."
}
```

I don't what is wrong here ? my project_id ? job_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first instance, verify that your project exists in the eu-gb region (rather than Dallas for example).

Another quick test is to use the [JobLists](https://api.eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/v2/jobs/docs/swagger/#/Jobs/jobs_list) API supplying the project-id to obtain a list of jobs which you can then verify.

If you are using the incorrect region or project-id, then the '"CATSV5025E: Unable to find Catalog for project ....' occurs.

If you are using dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com then the API endpoint is https://api.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/

Please note that your project ID was visible in the error message which you included.

Also note that projects created in one region are not visible in another region.